# Data Binding Successful but propertychange remains null

Tags: c#, wpf

I had successfully implemented a databind before but now it has stop working... After putting in some breakpoints I have noticed that the PropertyChange event remains null. I looked up several "solutions" involving using DataContext (not sure where to put it) but still didnt work...

Thanks for any help!

It works for the first initial bind but after it does not wok (when the property changes)

My Code:
My Binding:

```
        //databinding
        Binding(newProjectile.CurrentVelocity, lbl_angleoftraveloutput, "AngleOfTravel");

    private void Binding(velocity Object, Label Output, string Field)
    {
        Binding newBinding = new Binding();
        newBinding.Source = Object;
        newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        newBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Field);
        newBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        Output.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, newBinding);
    }
```

My Object (Part of it):

```
public class velocity : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable
{
    public double AngleOfTravel
    {
        get { return _AngleOfTravel; }
        set
        {
            _AngleOfTravel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AngleOfTravel");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler Handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed your code. In the button click event - LoadStaticsAndStart you have a statement newParticle.CurrentVelocity = newParticle.InitialVelocity; whic his causing the issue. newParticle.CurrentVelocity is bound to the UI Labels so it will have INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation. But newParticle.InitialVelocity is not bound with UI so it will not have INotifyPropertyChanged so I have commented the line and the UI update for you output labels are working now. Replace the function with the below function.

```
 private void LoadStaticsAndStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        DrawAxis();
        List<velocity> velocityList = new List<velocity>();
        double[,] DisplacementArray = new double[59, 1];
        btn_Calculate.Click += OnLoaded;
        particle newParticle;
        velocity InitialVelocity = new velocity();
        ObjectsAndDataStuctures.Environment newEnvironment;
        if (FormatCheck(txtb_AngleOLaunch) == false || FormatCheck(txtbox_InitialVelocity) == false || FormatCheck(txtbox_TimeOfFlight) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Input is not valid");
        }
        else
        {
            newEnvironment = new ObjectsAndDataStuctures.Environment();
            newEnvironment.gravity = -9.8; // gravity remove when needed or changed
            InitialVelocity.Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_InitialVelocity.Text); // collecting variables.
            InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel = Convert.ToDouble(txtb_AngleOLaunch.Text); // collecting variables.
            newParticle = new particle(InitialVelocity, Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_TimeOfFlight.Text));
            stk_pnl_inputvar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            CreateLabels(newParticle);
            newParticle.CalculateHComponent();
            newParticle.CalculateVComponent();
            MPP(newParticle, newEnvironment);
            OnLoaded(this, e);
            if (Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_TimeOfFlight.Text) > 60)
            {
                TimeConstant = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_TimeOfFlight.Text) / 60;
            }
            else
            {
                TimeConstant = 1;
            }
            double HVelTemp = newParticle.InitialVelocity.HorizontalVelocity * PixelPerMeter;
            double VVelTemp = newParticle.InitialVelocity.VerticalVelocity * PixelPerMeter * -1;
            Velocity = new Vector(HVelTemp, VVelTemp); // y direction is downwards
            acceleration = new Vector(0, -1 * newEnvironment.gravity * PixelPerMeter); // y direction is downwards
            aTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            aTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
            //newParticle.CurrentVelocity = newParticle.InitialVelocity;
            //this.DataContext = this;
            TimerEvent = (s, t) => onTimedEvent(sender, t, newParticle, newEnvironment);
            aTimer.Tick += TimerEvent;
            ListOfVelocities.Add((velocity)newParticle.CurrentVelocity.Clone());
            InSimulation = true;
            aTimer.Start();
        } 
    }
```

if you want to assign you InitialVelocity with CurrentVelocity Assign property by property. Like this below

```
  newParticle.CurrentVelocity.AngleOfTravel = newParticle.InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel;
                newParticle.CurrentVelocity.HorizontalVelocity = newParticle.InitialVelocity.HorizontalVelocity;
                newParticle.CurrentVelocity.Magnitude = newParticle.InitialVelocity.Magnitude;
                newParticle.CurrentVelocity.VerticalVelocity = newParticle.InitialVelocity.VerticalVelocity;
```

Comment: sorry i copied an pasted the wrong thing :/ i only copied and pasted part of my object - edited now

Comment: I still have the same problem :/ it binds at the start but as the value changes it the event is still null

Comment: is it a problem if i have multiple fields for one propertychange event?

Comment: I edited my post. I tried to change value in button click the value is changed. Pls refer the code.

Comment: sent it! ive included the class and where it is called, is that all? or do you need more

Comment: I had gone through it but not getting any clues.

Comment: any luck? im not sure how to handle this :/